# when I try to upload a file using Jquery its throwing error

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, automation

My code is throwing this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
> (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

```java
public expenseRequestPage clickToElement() {
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  URL jqueryUrl = Resources.getResource("jquery-1.8.2.min.js");
  String jqueryText = null;

  try {
    jqueryText = Resources.toString(jqueryUrl, Charsets.UTF_8);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  jse.executeScript(jqueryText);
  jse.executeScript("$(\"input[id$='fafa']\").click()");
  jse.executeScript("$(\"input[id$='fafa']\").val(\"C:\\Users\\Gayathri\\Documents\\EBPAutomation\\WBPTest\\src\\test\\resources\\FERPA.docx\")");
  return this;
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're trying to set the value of a `input type="file"` element, which is not possible for obvious security reasons. Note that this has nothing to do with uploading a file as your title suggests.

Comment: Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Also, as an aside, note that jquery 1.8.2 is incredibly outdated and has security issues. You should really look to upgrade it to the latest version, 3.6.0 at time of writing

Comment: No. It would be a massive security flaw if it was possible.

Comment: You can simply use `sendKyes(filepath)` on `input` tag which has `type=file` attibute

Answer (score 0):

When you try to upload a file from your computer to a site using Selenium, you don't use JavaScript injection. Use element.sendKeys on the element that should get the file to be uploaded to the site.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);
 WebElement elementToFind = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
 presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(elementId)));
 elementToFind.sendKeys(keys);
```

In the example above keys parameter should hold the path to the file.